# Vertically center logo and title in HTML 5

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, html-head

I am trying to create a responsive version of my portfolio website and I am nesting my logo image and title inside the header tag. The older version used divs to float the logo and title on the left and right sides of the header.

Here is where I got stuck at when I tried to space the `img` and `h1` without using `divs`.
The title is placed at the top right corner, but I don't know how to vertically center both `img` and `h1` without using the older methods.

**Layout as of Now**

[image: Current Layout]

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="203" height="41" alt="logo for Design415.com" class="logo">
    <h1 class="pagetitle">PORTFOLIO TITLE</h1>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    background-color: #333333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.pagetitle {
    position: absolute; 
    right:0; 
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1.40em; 
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of what layout you want?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1iZMFQ0TNChRVlQaC1hLWlCN2s/edit?hl=en&forcehl=1

Comment: You might consider writing future titles differently. You actually have a specific, on-topic question about your HTML and CSS, but your title makes it sound like an off-topic/not-constructive question.

Answer (score 0):

To center the text vertically add `line-height: 60px`:

```
.pageTitle {
    // Your styles here
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

To center the image vertically, change the margin on top:

```
.logo {
    // Your styles here
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

Here is a **[working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/9vMLv/)**.